# Shouldn't calling Enumerable.AsEnumerable() on null variable throw an exception?

Tags: c#, linq

I had a piece of code that used this expression - `someCollection.AsEnumerable()`. Later on I realized that, in some cases the `someCollection` was set to `null`. However, I never got any exception from this code. I even ran it through the debugger. If I remember correctly, the expression `someCollection.AsEnumerable()` evaluated to `null` if `someCollection` was set to `null`.

Shouldn't calling `someCollection.AsEnumerable()` throw an exception if `someCollection` was set to `null`? Am I missing something?

Comment: The method literally does absolutely nothing but pass the value through as an `IEnumerable`, which will succeed for `null` just fine. To give an error on a `null` value, it would need to add an explicit check. Would such a check be worth it/correct? Well, *kind of* -- you could definitely argue that a `null` `IEnumerable` is still an `IEnumerable` and it did its job just fine, but on the other hand extension methods are typically expected to do their best to behave as if they were normal methods, so... whether intended or not, changing it now would probably be breaking something somewhere.

Comment: You couldn't argue that null is still an IEnumerable. null has no type, no properties, inherits and implements nothing. Its not an object. Its certainly not enumerable. This happens because it is an extension method, which is just syntactic sugar. You aren't actually calling a method on null here, you are calling a method that takes null as a parameter. This is why calling a method, except extensions, DOES throw a null reference exception. Its a symptom of what is going on behind the scenes. Extension methods are just static methods that take the object as a param.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AsEnumerable` is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). It's defined [like this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3ee4ab000402fbeb):

```
public static class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

It's valid to call extension methods on `null` -- writing `someCollection.AsEnumerable()` is just syntactic sugar for writing `Enumerable.AsEnumerable(someCollection)`. You'd be surprised if you wrote `Enumerable.AsEnumerable(null)` and got a `NullReferenceException`!

As you can see, there's no test for `null` inside `AsEnumerable` - if it's passed `null`, it will just return `null`.

---

`AsEnumerable` could have been written to contain an explicit test for `null` -- `if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));` (which would throw an `ArgumentNullException`, rather than a `NullReferenceException`).

But, from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8):

> The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself.

If you have a `null` typed as an `IQueryable<T>`, I think it's perfectly valid for this method to turn it into a `null` typed as an `IEnumerable<T>`. `null` is after all a perfectly valid `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Another way of looking at this is, what's to be gained from throwing an exception if the `source` is `null`? The method can work perfectly fine it it's passed `null`, and that might be useful to someone.

Comment: Its a bit of a misnomer to say that `null` can be typed. If that were true you could call methods on `null` if it was assigned to an object. You were right in the beginning, this is because extension methods are just syntactic sugar for static methods that take that object as a parameter.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I think (hope!) it's fairly clear from context that I mean `(IQueryable<T>)null`, etc. Whether null can be typed is a bit more woolly: in `IL`, null very much has a type, and if you try and call a method on the wrong type of null, your assembly won't verify. In early C# versions you could also call non-virtual instance methods on a null reference, and this worked just fine - the `call` instruction supports that. This was changed (`callvirt` was used instead) to avoid confusion later on. [Also see here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,571)

Comment: This explains it quite well. My lack of understanding of C# Extension Methods led me to this confusion.